# An error occurred while fetching comments.

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, deleted-questions

[image]

Is there any limit on the number of comments on an answer or is it a technical fault?

Comment: Probably a technical problem. This usually happens when the post gets deleted, or when there is a network glitch.

Comment: Does it recur on reload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit on the amount of comments.

When you follow the URL in the screenshot (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326490/why-is-stack-overflow-refusing-to-delete-my-account) you can see that the question was deleted.

This is why you can't fetch the comments anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Next build will introduce a better error message when fetching comments on a deleted post:

> This post has been deleted and its comments are no longer available

Note this only applies to users without the [Moderator tools privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).